# Help on adding color option to chapter title

Tags: sectioning, memoir, chapters, titlesec

I'm trying to create an option to easily change a color bar in a chapter title. This code works on changing the color of the bar, but ruins the formatting. All of the chapter text is to be aligned with the right hand margin of the first chapter page. Thanks in advance for any recommendations. James[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

```
\documentclass[twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{blindtext, fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\colorlet{LightRubineRed}{RubineRed!70!}
\colorlet{Mycolor1}{green!10!orange!90!}
\definecolor{Mycolor2}{HTML}{00F9DE}

%% below is a poor close color option, does what it should but can't use \titleformat
\renewcommand{\colorChapter}[2]{\chapter[Black display]
    {\normalfont\Large\raggedleft}
    {\MakeUppercase{#2}%
    \rlap{ \resizebox{!}{1.2cm}{\thechapter} \textcolor{#1}{\rule{15cm}{1.2cm}} } }
    {10pt}{\Huge}}


\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{30pt}{20pt}
%% \addtolength{\evensidemargin}{.875in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{.999in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{-1.00in}

\begin{document}
\colorChapter{Blue}{What are Family Values}
```

---

```
%% ===================================================
%% DIFFERENT CODE THAT PRODUCES THE DESIRED FORMAT
%% The following code produces the desired format, but it can not be used to change %% colors between different chapters.
\documentclass[twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{blindtext, fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\colorlet{LightRubineRed}{RubineRed!70!}
\colorlet{Mycolor1}{green!10!orange!90!}
\definecolor{Mycolor2}{HTML}{00F9DE}

%% This works but can not change color of bar from chapter to chapter
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\normalfont\Large\raggedleft}
    {\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}%
    \rlap{ \resizebox{!}{1.2cm}{\thechapter} \textcolor{Blue}{\rule{15cm}{1.2cm}} } }
    {10pt}{\Huge}

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{30pt}{20pt}
%% \addtolength{\evensidemargin}{.875in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{.999in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{-1.00in}


\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{What are Family Values}

\epigraph{\textit{We can choose our values. }}{Dr. Phil's Dad}
\section{First section}
\blindtext
\section{Second Section}
Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper,
felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignis-
sim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut,
ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in sapien.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis
fringilla tristique neque. Sed interdum libero ut metus. Pellen-
tesque placerat. Nam rutrum augue a leo. Morbi sed elit sit
amet ante lobortis sollicitudin. Praesent blandit blandit mau-
ris. Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a,
turpis. Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc quis urna
dictum turpis accumsan semper.

Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper,
felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignis-
sim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut,
ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in sapien.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 

Duis fringilla tristique neque. Sed interdum libero ut metus. Pellen-
tesque placerat. Nam rutrum augue a leo. Morbi sed elit sit
amet ante lobortis sollicitudin. Praesent blandit blandit mau-
ris. Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a,
turpis. Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc quis urna
dictum turpis accumsan semper.

\end{document}
```

[image: code that produces desired format, but can't change color among chapters]

Comment: Can you please show as an image of the desired result? Which exactly should be the position of the color bar?

Comment: Also, can you please provide a complete test document? Most of the times (and this is one of those times), just code snippets are not useful.

Comment: BTW: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 4):

With the `memoir` class you can define your own chapter styles without the need of the `titlesec` package.

The style you're trying to achieve is very similar to the predefined `veelo` style.

So it suffices to change it a little. We'll define a new chapter style `colored`:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\chaptercolor}{}
\makechapterstyle{colored}{%
  \setlength{\afterchapskip}{40pt}
  \renewcommand*{\chapterheadstart}{\vspace*{40pt}}
  \renewcommand*{\afterchapternum}{\par\nobreak\vskip 25pt}
   \renewcommand*{\chapnamefont}{\normalfont\Large\flushright}
   \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\normalfont}
   \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\Huge\flushright}
   \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{%
     \chapnamefont\MakeTextUppercase{\@chapapp}}
   \renewcommand*{\chapternamenum}{}
  \setlength{\beforechapskip}{1.2cm}%  \numberheight
  \setlength{\midchapskip}{\paperwidth}% \barlength
  \addtolength{\midchapskip}{-\textwidth}
   \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{%
     \makebox[0pt][l]{%
       \hspace{.8em}%
       \resizebox{!}{\beforechapskip}{\chapnumfont \thechapter}%
       \hspace{.8em}%
       \textcolor{\chaptercolor}{\rule{\midchapskip}{\beforechapskip}}%
     }%
   }%
   \makeoddfoot{plain}{}{\thepage}{}}
\makeatother
```

and use it in the document through the command

```
\chapterstyle{colored}
```

At this point let's define a new command `\colorchapter`

```
\newcommand{\colorchapter}[3][]{\renewcommand{\chaptercolor}{#3}\chapter[#1]{#2}}
```

to be used in this way (for example):

```
\colorchapter{What are Family Values}{Blue}
```

With the following MWE

```
\documentclass[twoside]{memoir} 
\usepackage{blindtext} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} 
\colorlet{LightRubineRed}{RubineRed!70!} 
\colorlet{Mycolor1}{green!10!orange!90!} 
\definecolor{Mycolor2}{HTML}{00F9DE}


\makeatletter
\newcommand{\chaptercolor}{}
\makechapterstyle{colored}{%
  \setlength{\afterchapskip}{40pt}
  \renewcommand*{\chapterheadstart}{\vspace*{40pt}}
  \renewcommand*{\afterchapternum}{\par\nobreak\vskip 25pt}
   \renewcommand*{\chapnamefont}{\normalfont\Large\flushright}
   \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\normalfont}
   \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\Huge\flushright}
   \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{%
     \chapnamefont\MakeTextUppercase{\@chapapp}}
   \renewcommand*{\chapternamenum}{}
  \setlength{\beforechapskip}{1.2cm}%  \numberheight
  \setlength{\midchapskip}{\paperwidth}% \barlength
  \addtolength{\midchapskip}{-\textwidth}
   \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{%
     \makebox[0pt][l]{%
       \hspace{.8em}%
       \resizebox{!}{\beforechapskip}{\chapnumfont \thechapter}%
       \hspace{.8em}%
       \textcolor{\chaptercolor}{\rule{\midchapskip}{\beforechapskip}}%
     }%
   }%
   \makeoddfoot{plain}{}{\thepage}{}}
\makeatother

\chapterstyle{colored}

\newcommand{\colorchapter}[3][]{\renewcommand{\chaptercolor}{#3}\chapter[#1]{#2}}

%% \addtolength{\evensidemargin}{.875in} 
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{.999in} 
\addtolength{\textwidth}{-1.00in}

\usepackage{lipsum} 

\begin{document} 

\colorchapter{What are Family Values}{Blue}

\epigraph{\textit{We can choose our values. }}{Dr. Phil's Dad} 

\section{First section} 
\lipsum[1] 
\section{Second Section} 
\lipsum[1] 

\colorchapter{What are Family Values}{LightRubineRed}

\epigraph{\textit{We can choose our values. }}{Dr. Phil's Dad}

\section{First section}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Second Section}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

the result will be

[image]